# AccountManager - authToken is set but peekAuthToken return null

Tags: android, facebook, accountmanager

I'm trying to add a new account (after a Facebook login + server
   validation) in AccountManager. The flow for this case is like this:

1. User login with Facebook
2. I got the details after the login is done and I validate them against the data I have on my server
3. If everything is ok, the server send back an auth_token (JWT token)
4. Having user's details and the auth_token I'm creating an account via AccountManager and once it is created, I set the authToken for
   it.
5. On next login when the user will re-open the app I call getAuthToken which first try to get the cached authToken by calling peekAuthToken().

*The problem*

At point 5, peekAuthToken returns **null** but it shouldn't because I already set the autToken for that account.

*Code*

```
 public static Bundle handleUserLogin(Context context, User user) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account account = new Account(user.getEmail(), ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    boolean isNewAccount = true;


    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if (user.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(accounts[i].name) && ACCOUNT_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(accounts[i].type)) {
            isNewAccount = false;
            account = accounts[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isNewAccount) {
        am.addAccountExplicitly(account, user.getPassword(), null);
        accounts = am.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            if (user.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(accounts[i].name) && ACCOUNT_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(accounts[i].type)) {
                account = accounts[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (null != user.getPassword()) {
        am.setPassword(account, user.getPassword());
    }

    Cs.error(TAG, "account " + account + " token " + user.getToken());
    am.setAuthToken(account, user.getToken(), Authenticator.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS);
    setUserData(user, account, am);

    Bundle result = new Bundle();

    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, user.getToken());
    mPrefs.edit().putString(Constants.KEY_CURRENT_USER, account.name).commit();

    return result;
}
```

First I thought that maybe the reference to my new account is not the correct one (ex the one from AccountManager) so I search for account again.

Could you give me some indications about what I'm doing wrong or how should I make sure the authToken will be set for an account?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on explicit setting authToken in place different than in [AbstractThreadedAccountAuthenticator's getAuthToken()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#getAuthToken(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) method. 
My guess is that the authToken is not cached yet when you request it.

I suggest just creating account via [AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addAccountExplicitly(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) and deferring accessing authToken once you really need it.

In [AbstractThreadedAccountAuthenticator's getAuthToken()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#getAuthToken(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) I suggest applying logic like in the project I created a while ago.

1. Request authToken via AccountManager.peekAuthToken()
2. If authToken is set in cache then return it.
3. If not then request it from your server then cache via [AccountManager.setAuthToken()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#setAuthToken(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and finally return.

Link: https://github.com/dawidgdanski/AccountAuthenticatorExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authenticator/account/auth/SimpleAuthenticator.java

Hope this will help you out:

https://github.com/dawidgdanski/AccountAuthenticatorExample

Comment: Please include some explaination in your answer as well. I think you're talking about https://github.com/dawidgdanski/AccountAuthenticatorExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authenticator/account/auth/SimpleAuthenticator.java ?